# How can I proceed regarding a possibly-lost letter when travelling?

Tags: mail, south-america

I sent a letter from **Montevideo, Uruguay** to **Romania**, via the Uruguay Post. At the post office they told me it would arrive after 15 days.

It has been almost 30 days and the letter did not arrive. Since I am traveling, I am not in Montevideo anymore and I am not sure what I should do to check the package.

The package does not have a tracking number, and that's why I guess that even if I would contact the post office they would not be able to help much...

I do hope it is just delaying, but is there anything else I can do rather than just waiting?

Comment: Was it something like recorded delivery ? You can try getting in touch in Romania, but without any tracking I don't think it will be of much help either.

Comment: @DumbCoder I think it's just a _simple letter_ without tracking or anything like that... From my experience with the Romanian Post they don't check based on the address even if the package has a tracking number... They have the mapping between tracking numbers and the package metadata written physically in a notebook, by hand. For some packages they do provide online tracking, but that never worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted the post office but since the letter did not have any tracking number, it was impossible to track.

If the package *does* have a tracking number, it is easier to follow.

If it does *not* have, then the only thing that can be done in general is to wait.  In my particular case, it delayed about a month and eventually arrived.